# Are there any inquiry based Calculus books?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation, big-list

This question may have been asked a bunch of times, but I have not found exactly what I was looking for.

I say calculus, but mathematical/real analysis works as well as long as it does not have calculus as a prequisite.

I have been looking for books that take an inquiry based approach, where the theory and everything else is build by solving problems with minimal explanations from the Author aside from introducing some definitions (Bogart's "[Combinatorics Through Guided Discovery](https://math.dartmouth.edu/news-resources/electronic/kpbogart/)" is exactly what I am looking for, but for calculus/analysis).

I am aware of [jiblm](https://jiblm.org/), but I was wondering if there are published books on calculus/analysis using this approach that may be more suitable for independent learners?

Comment: Your link to the Journal of Inquiry base Learning in Mathematics looks terrific. I quickly found a 78 page free downloadable published book, I would call it, on [Calculus I](https://jiblm.org/downloads/jiblmjournal/V190250S/V190250S.pdf).  What makes this not suitable for independent learners?

Comment: May I ask a question on Bogart's book through which I just skimmed briefly: does the author provide solutions to the problems for self-checking?

Comment: Not that I know of, at least in the book itself not. Usually there are other exercises that suggest a different approach and may help point out inconsistencies if there has been a mistake in the reasoning in any of the previous problems.

Comment: Also, I'm not saying that the jiblm material is not suitable for independent learners, just that it is material mostly used in classrooms which in most cases has some direction from the professors who may provide additional problems and notes on topics that may not be in the book.